# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.1 elasticbeanstalk .net core app running on docker

Tags: c#, docker, amazon-ec2, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have .net core app running in docker, when I deploying image to amazon Elastic Beanstalk, status is ok, however when I am trying access the page i am getting "502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.1"

DockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR  /src
COPY ["MyApp.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR . /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
"Name": "xxxx/myapp",
"Update": "true"
},
"Ports": [
{
  "ContainerPort": "80"
}
 ]
}
```

log:

```
2019/07/16 10:55:34 [error] 13553#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.32.153.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.3:80/", host: "myapp-env11.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"
```

What Port should I open in order for this to run?

Comment: Thrashing on this same thing.  Ever figure this out?

Comment: So no one figured this out? @kaszanka how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

So I was having this same issue earlier today. It turns out it was an issue with my application failing to start so, the nginx couldn't reach it.

And after going through the logs. I found out that it was a connection string issue, because my application was starting locally and when I deployed to IIS but not when its deployed to AWS elastic-beanstalk.

My application wasn't a dockerized application but this same issue almost gave me a terrible day.

**So, here is what I will advise, download your logs and look through the logs for any application specific error, in my case I had to check the web.stdout logs.**

So I fixed my connection string issue.

From:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=dbserverURL,1433;Database=DbName;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbPass;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

To:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=dbserverURL,1433;Database=DbName;Integrated Security=false;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```